# How to correctly passed php mysql data to ChartJs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, chart.js

I want to be able to produce bar chart and pie charts using ChartJs. I'm using php and mysql to get the data. The bar chart that I want to produce is a chart that shows the stats of students who are male or female and the sum of students also. Here is an example of how I want the result to appear:

[image]

It may not be exactly like it, but I feels it gives an idea. I'm problems with my code which I don't seem to understand, because I'm a novice to ChartJs and is just trying it out, since morris.js isn't being fully supported. Here is how my code looks:

Html

```
<div class="box box-success">
        <div class="box box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Student Chart</h3>
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <canvas id="mycanvas" style="height:230px;"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Script:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      type: 'GET',
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var male = [];
        var female = [];

        for(var count in data){
          male.push(data[count].male);
          female.push(data[count].female);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: male,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Student Gender',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                hoverbackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                hoverborderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                data:female
              }
            ] 
        };

        var ctx = $('#mycanvas');

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
          type:'bar',
          data: chartdata
        });
      },
      error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

data.php

```
$query = "SELECT  
            SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Male,
            SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female
          FROM students";

$output = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    # code...
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        # code...
        $output[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    die("There was a problem". mysqli_error($connection));
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Here is the result I'm getting from the console:

[{"Male":"5","Female":"2"}]

Will appreciate suggestion on how I can make it better and do the same for pie chart also.

Based on what I've done this is how my chart is displaying:

[image]

**Note** Please ignored the frequency on the photo.

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest you to change your sql query to following.

```
$query = "select gender,count(gender) as count from students group by gender";
$output = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    # code...
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        # code...
        $output[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    die("There was a problem". mysqli_error($connection));
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

script:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      type: 'GET',
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var gender = [];
        var sum = [];

        for(var count in data){
          gender.push(data[count].gender);
          sum.push(data[count].total);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: gender,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Student Gender',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                hoverbackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                hoverborderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                data:sum
              }
            ] 
        };

        var ctx = $('#mycanvas');

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
          type:'bar',
          data: chartdata
        });
      },
      error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I have adopted my code to match yours and this is the result I'm getting from the console: [{"gender":"Female","total":"2"},{"gender":"Male","total":"5"}] but the chart is still displaying the same.

Comment: I have updated code as you have "total" as the second field .. check now..

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the problem was with my script. Big thanks to @milan kumar for helping with the query. What was missing was specification of the type of data I was sending to ajax. All I had to do was to add the **dataType** with value 'json' before the success function, and it work perfectly. This is how the code should look:

script:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      type: 'GET',
      // this was what I needed to make it work.
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data){

        var gender = [];
        var sum = [];

        for(var i in data){
          gender.push(data[i].gender);
          sum.push(data[i].total);
        }

        var ChartData = {
            labels: ['Student Gender'],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: gender[0],
                fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data:sum[0]
              },
              {
                label: gender[1],
                fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
                pointColor: "#3b8bba",
                pointStrokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
                data:sum[1]
              }
            ] 
        };
      });
```

I have added some optional attributes to beautify my chart.