# ChartJS Arrays Acting as One Item

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, chart.js

I'm trying to import readings from mySQL database, and place them on a ChartJS.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM readings 
ORDER BY readings_id DESC LIMIT 2");

$distance = array();
$timestamp = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $distance[] = $row['river_height'];
   $time[] = $row['time_stamp'];
}
```

This is the query I'm using and the method I'm doing to store readings in an array.

However, when I try to place these in a bar chart for example, the 2 readings will act as one.
[image]
I have the Javascript code as follows:

```
const time = <?php echo json_encode($time); ?>;
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("chart");

var config = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: [time],
      datasets: [{data:[10, 20]}],
   }
}
```

I've tried quite a lot of things, but can't figure it out. I'm new to this, so it doesn't help. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any personal experience with ChartJS, but your scripting doesn't quite look like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252799/2943403  If your PHP and MySQL are working as expected, then we shouldn't see them mentioned in your question body.  Please narrow down what's wrong and try to show us as little as possible so that we have an easier time helping you to debug.

Comment: What if you remove the square braces from around `time`?  It is an indexed array -- it will already have square braces around it.  Why declare `const time` at all?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns a "result set object" not a `query`.  You can feed that result set object directly into a `foreach()` and iterate the result set as an indexed array of associative arrays instead of calling `fetch` over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your PHP is returning an array for the labels and then you put that array in another array. This tells chart.js that it has to be a multiline label as you can see.
To get the behaviour you want you need to remove the array brackets at the labels field like so:

```js
const time = <?php echo json_encode($time); ?>;
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("chart");

var config = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: time, // remove array brackets around time
      datasets: [{data:[10, 20]}],
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `time_stamp` as the X axis, and `river_height` as the Y axis, change to :

PHP :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $data[] = [
      'x' => $row['time_stamp'],
      'y' => $row['river_height']
   ];
}
```

JavaScript :

```
var config = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      datasets: [{
         data: <?= json_encode($data) ?>
      }]
   }
};
```